# Android Theme Background applies also to title bar

Tags: android, android-theme

I am designing an andriod theme in which I want to change the background of all the activities. I am using the following code:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_gradient</item>
</style>
```

The problem is that the background applies also to the title bar. How can I apply the background only to the content please?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a base activity then set the background in this activity, then all your activities can inherit the base activity.

All you can override the titlebarbackground in your theme:

```
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@color/yourtitlebarcolor</item>
```